# Linecharting Toolkit for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This might be the wrong place, but anyway.

I am looking for a charting tool for WPF, that is easy stylable and contains a linechart. By no I found this toolkit: http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/ but it doesn't offer a linechart. The WPF Toolkit chart seems to hard to be styled and now I have no idea where to look further.

The toolkit must be free and should be open source. Sadly, googleing didn't help me.

Comment: Not open source, but you could always host the WinForms chart control in you WPF app. Would that solution work for you?

Comment: @LordTakkera Not sure, cause I would like to MVVM. SparrowChart looks fairly good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OxyPlot](http://oxyplot.codeplex.com/) is an open source line charting / plotting library that seems to be taken care of quite well. I also found [GraphIT](http://graphit.codeplex.com/) which is open source too.