# Simple Charting / Graphing tool for WPF (C#

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit, timeserieschart

What do people use these days for graphing (charting) simple time series data in WPF?  My needs are simple: graph time series of roughly 5000 points and be able to zoom in/out on sections. It would also be nice to have multiple time series on one graph.  I want to get something up and running quickly with a minimum of fuss.  I'm analyzing the data analytically, and the chart is just for demo purposes.

I much prefer a free/open source solution.  If it can be done from standard .NET libraries, so much the better.
I saw mention of OxyPlot ( [Linecharting Toolkit for WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22671239/linecharting-toolkit-for-wpf))
and in the same reference they mention the WPF Toolkit.  However, I don't see any charting tools in the WPF toolkit (I downloaded it through NuGet Package Manager so perhaps I'm not get the right one?)

I also saw that Windows Forms (not WPF) has a chart control: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456753.aspx

Note that all of the above references are quite out of date.

Can someone recommend a solution?
Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Thanks for bringing WPF chart controls [closed] 13 answers to my attention.  It's over 5 years old but if there has been nothing new since, then that will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

The link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456753.aspx covers details for creating chart in `Wpf` application. Only drawback is that these charts are not flashy by default and you have to write/customize style to make them attractive.

Comment: Thanks Sham.  I did notice this one.  Notice that the latest version is 2012!  You'd think they would have updated since then.